# Django view decorator accessing 'self'

Tags: python, django, decorator, self

I'm trying to call `self` in my decorator but I get errors. Some background first:

I have the following models:

```
Car(models.Model):
   user = ForeignKey(User)
   color = models.CharField(max_length=25)

Location(models.Model):
   user = ForeignKey(User)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I want to have URLs to edit the city/color like:
`/edit/<model-name>/<model-id>`, but I want to ensure that this is only accessible if `request.user` is the same as `model_instance.user`. So I have the following views:

```
class EditView(View):
    ThisModel = Model

    def get(self, request, model_id):
        instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
        if instance.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You can't do this!")
        else:
            # return form
            return render(request, 'my_template.html', context={'form':form})

    def post(request, model_id):
        instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
        if instance.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You can't do this!")
        else:
            # save form
            return HttpResponse('Edit successful.')

class EditCarView(EditView):
    ThisModel = Car

class EditLocationView(EditView):
    ThisModel = Location
```

Instead of repeating the `instance=...` lines common to both the `get` and `post` methods, I want to use a decorator. I tried this:

```
def current_user_only(func):
    def _check_curr_user(view_func):
        def _testview(self, request, model_id, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance = self.ThisModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
            if self.instance.user != request.user:
                return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden.")
            else:
                return view_func(request, username, *args, **kwargs)

        _testview.__name__ = view_func.__name__
        _testview.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
        _testview.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__

        return _testview

    return _check_curr_user(func)
```

And use this in my views:

```
@method_decorator(current_user_only, name='dispatch')
EditView(View):
```

But I get an error that `_testview` is missing one positional argument, `request`. How do I make this decorator work? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same issue and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It's been such a long time, sorry I've forgotten...

Answer (score 0):

In you case I think you have to use,

`@method_decorator(current_user_only, name='dispatch')
EditView(View):`

You may like to read [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Comment: Ah yes, I used `name='dispatch'`, sorry for the mistake. But I still get the same error.

Comment: I've also edited the code. Seems that Django requires that `_testview` has `request` as a "required positional argument". But if I put `self` there, it can't find `request`...